# Declined NAA flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Answer that I had flagged: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40677185/2142994

In the question the OP has mentioned the format in which he used the command. The spelling of password happened to be wrong and this answer just pointed it out. (I corrected the spelling now)

I flagged the answer NAA as it's not an answer to the question. NAA was declined:
[image: NAA Declined snap]

Comment: The asker didn't acknowledge the typo. You shouldn't be editing questions to fix typos in code on behalf of other users.

Comment: `passoword`  was a placeholder for the actual password there. It's not a parameter. I don't understand why the question got closed and deleted. It doesn't seem like a typo question.

Comment: @ayhan You are right, but by now, there is not really any point in restoring it. It has been over a year, and even if it wasn’t a typo, the question is still very unclear.

Comment: @BoltClock read that question again. `passoword` is just a placeholder. You could even change it to `PWD`, it wouldn't matter because that's not what the OP used. Plus the OP has replied in his comments that his problem wasn't solved, I am not sure why the question was closed..

Comment: @BoltClock "The asker didn't acknowledge the typo." because it wasn't a typo.
Do not change a meta question to something else entirely, just because you interpreted it wrong.

Comment: @Ani Menon: "The spelling of password happened to be wrong [...] (I corrected the spelling now)" So was it a typo or not?

Comment: @BoltClock the typo didn't make a difference. I corrected it but that's not what the OP asked!

Comment: If the person who answered didn't realize that it was just a placeholder then their post was still an attempt to answer, even if it was wrong. I'm under 10K though, so I can't see it. Does the answer say/imply they know they're not answering the question but can't comment?

Comment: An attempt to answer is an answer, even if it's crap, wrong or misguided.

Comment: @BSMP it was a new user who couldn't comment and had said that they had spelt password wrong. It was definitely an attempt to answer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I declined that flag because, as the decline reason says,

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

## Background

Image of the question for <10k users:

[image]

*Note: the "password" in the command above originally said, "passoword". The author of this Meta question [edited out the typo](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36023329/revisions).*

Image of the answer for <10k users:

[image]

## Explanation

The "answer" in question did not, in fact, correctly answer the question. But it was written as an *apparent attempt to answer* the question. Thus, I didn't delete it. In that case, the appropriate course of action for you would be to downvote or leave a comment.

Also, as [BoltClock wrote in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352317/declined-naa-flag#comment493070_352317):

> The asker didn't acknowledge the typo. You shouldn't be editing questions to fix typos in code on behalf of other users.

You and other users have pointed out that "passoword" was a placeholder, not a parameter name. But you haven't asked yourselves more important questions:

- Did the OP know that?
- That is, are you 100% sure the OP isn't using "password" as the actual password for testing purposes, but misspelling it?

  - And if you *are* 100% sure of that, ask, "*Why* am I sure of that?" Nothing in the question inspires that much confidence.
- Even more importantly: **Does the author of the answer know that?** If the author of the answer *thinks*, incorrectly, that the typo matters and might be the reason for the problem, then this was a legitimate attempt to answer the question and should not be flagged.

## The Philosophy of SO Flags

The moderation team has *very* limited bandwidth and a flood of flags to handle. This means that only issues that **require** moderator intervention should be flagged.

I would recommend reading this classic post: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) As explained there, even a wrong or unhelpful answer is an answer. Put differently, here's an example:

> **Question:** What's `2 + 2`?
>
> **Answer:** Great question! I want to know that too! *[Flag as NAA]*
>
> **Answer:** You're ugly. *[Flag as NAA or abusive]*
>
> **Answer:** dswberkfsshwe. *[Flag as NAA or abusive]*
>
> **Answer:** Let me Google that for you (or "Go read this blog post" or "Here's a link to another SO answer). *[Flag as VLQ]*
>
> **Answer:** Buy WOW coins here. *[Flag as spam]*
>
> **Answer:** `42`. *[Completely wrong, but **still an answer**. Downvote or leave a comment, but do not flag.]*

Comment: It's a fairly reasonable assumption that the password is a placeholder, I'll give them that.

Comment: For the last one, the answer was correct, just the question wasn't. 

Comment: @Cœur Well played.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of the rejection reason is that the moderator believed that it was a good faith answer, that just happened to be wrong for the problem. For these cases, we shouldn't flag the post for deletion. The stated reasoning is that the moderators shouldn't be expected to evaluate the technical merit of each answer. This wouldn't be scalable, so instead we should limit ourselves to downvoting the answer, if it is wrong. A comment also can be helpful for other users not be distracted/mislead by the answer.

Comment: NAA is to be used when a user responded with something that doesn't answer the question. It was earlier down-voted. The problem is someone thought that it was a solution to the question and closed the question, that shouldn't happen. **To avoid such things, pointing out typos should be comments not answers.**

Comment: I do agree with your point, moderators can't be expected to judge the technical merit of an answer.

Comment: But new users can't comment... So it's either an answer or nothing for them. This doesn't mean that they can use answers for things that don't answer the question, but in this case he seemed to believe that it was the answer to the problem, even though it clearly wasn't the correct one.

Comment: Yes. Anyhow, that question and pointless answer is deleted so I think this question should be marked "status-completed"

Comment: @AniMenon Just to address your last comment: the [status-completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag is for when "A feature request has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, or a request has been processed." It's not used for discussion questions. We don't need to close this question or mark it complete, even if it's now moot.